# Content type or web form(creating own form using hooks) Which one is best way of collecting input from user?

Tags: javascript, theming, forms

I am new to Drupal and learning is in progress. I know about content types and creating webforms using hooks. Now I want to collect data from user and store it to db and view it later (easily I can do with a content type) but I need to apply some jQuery events. i.e. if user choose a country then in another drop down I want to show the states of that particular country and I want to change input style.

Which suits best for above problem and why not another one more suitable?

Comment: Have you read the form api docs? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to make your hands dirty playing with code then better use webform module as per your drupal version.
Webform module  in drupal gives you everything, you dont need to make further queries to manage the input data, its just a use of normal CMS. Better try with that, an in addition you can export data as well.
I hope this helps you.
Thanks

Comment: is it possible to apply hook_form_alter and other hook_** for those web forms(i am talking about web form module).?

Comment: yeah shridhar you can do that easily. no problem with that.

Comment: can u send some links which explains with examples.. read documentation but not got satisfied... please

Comment: Please follow the link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105608/drupal-form-alter-in-webform-forms
If its unclear then I can share you my piece of code that I did last time. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can do that, the way it is done in normal form. You can use all the normal hook that are used in form.
Thanks